# How to make pthreads workers properly using pthread_cond_signal and pthread_cond_wait?

Tags: c, pthreads

Trying to implement two parallel workers. After forming data I need to tell worker to take data and to process it. Here is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *worker(void *data);

struct worker_data_t
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    long id, data;
};

struct worker_data_t *workers_data;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int cpus = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    if (cpus < 1)
        cpus = 1;

    workers_data = (struct worker_data_t *)malloc(cpus * sizeof(struct worker_data_t));
    int ret_val[cpus];

    for (int i = 0; i < cpus; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&workers_data[i].mutex, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&workers_data[i].cond, NULL);
        workers_data[i].id = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cpus; i++)
        ret_val[i] = pthread_create(&workers_data[i].thread_id, NULL, worker, &workers_data[i]);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&workers_data[0].mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&workers_data[0].cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&workers_data[0].mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&workers_data[0].mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&workers_data[0].cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&workers_data[0].mutex);

    for (int i = 0; i < cpus; i++)
        pthread_join(workers_data[i].thread_id, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void *worker(void *data)
{
    struct worker_data_t d = *((struct worker_data_t*)(data));
    printf("Thread %d started\n", d.id);
    for (;;)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&workers_data[d.id].mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&workers_data[d.id].cond, &workers_data[d.id].mutex);
        printf("catch!\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&workers_data[d.id].mutex);
    }
}
```

After notifying worker by pthread_cond_signal nothing happens. If I put sleep(1) before each pthread_cond_signal block, it works.

What should be done to make it work without sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As R. said, and as he should have made into an answer, what you need is a *predicate*. This is something that you test to see if the condition is true.

In your case it should be a simple variable, protected by the `workers_data[0].mutex`.

Then in your worker, you lock the mutex, just as you already do, then check the predicate. If the predicate is true, you have no need to wait for the condition, so don't. Just go do what you need to do. If the predicate is false then wait on the condition.

One very important point not to forget is that the predicate must never be changed outside of the mutex lock used by the condition variable. If it is, the condition will get missed in some cases and that would lead to threads that get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The signal which is generated by `pthread_cond_signal()` is lost when there are no threads locked on the condvar referenced by that call. It is highly probable that the following will happen:

1. `main()` thread calls `pthread_create()`
2. `main()` thread executes 1 or more lock-signal-unlock blocks
3. child threads get processor time and become locked on `pthread_cond_wait()`. The signal is already lost, so they will never be woken up

It is undefined if a thread gets the CPU right after the call to `pthread_create()`. When you do `sleep(1)` before making signals, you give a chance for worker thread(s) to execute and start listening on their condvars. That is one of the ways to solve the problem. Still you may want to implement some kind of *ready check* to be sure that worker is waiting and your signal is not lost (create another condvar and signal it when the worker is ready for example). Another way to go here is to use semaphores.

Also have in mind that `pthread_join()` will never return in your program cause the workers have no way to leave the infinite loop. It is also advisable to check every `pthread_...()` return for an error, especially when you investigating some kind of unexpected program behavior.

Comment: While this answer is full of correct information, it fails to address the most important issue, which is that condition variables **can never be used without an associated predicate**.